# Qt & QWT: QwtPlotCurve - Curve not showing up

Tags: qt, plot, qwt

I want to show a simple graph using QWT and Qt Creator:

Qt version: 4.8.2, Qt Creator: 2.5.2,  QWT version: 6.0.0

I added a QwtPlot to my MainWindow (called "myPlot" in the example). Then I have a callback function which is called each time I press a button:

```
void MainWindow::forwardPlot()
{
    double x[9] = {1,20,30,40,50,60,70,200,500};
    double y[9] = {1,500,3,1,200,100,2,1,0};
    QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
    curve->setRawSamples(x,y,9);
    curve->attach( ui->myPlot );
    curve->show();
    ui->myPlot->replot();
    ui->label->setText("bla");
}
```

Compiling works fine...
The label is set to "bla", so I know that the callback function is called. But the curve is not displayed. I am able to resize myPlot for example. But showing the curve does not work. Any hints?

Comment: was `ui->myPlot` visible before? what happens if you add `ui->myPlot->show()`

Comment: No, I tried that already. Does not help :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your point arrays are on the stack and will be gone after leaving forwardPlot().

Answer (score 0):

1. You appear not to set the pen color for the curve:

   curve->setPen( QColor( Qt::green ) );
2. You need to set up the axis so Qwt knows which part of the plot to show:

   ui->myPlot->setAxisScale( QwtPlot::xBottom, 1.0, 500.0 );

   ui->myPlot->setAxisScale( QwtPlot::yLeft, 1.0, 500.0 );
3. I'd also set the title for the curve to see if your QwtPlot works at all:

   ui->myPlot->setTitle( "Plot title" );

**Edit:** I've reproduced the issue. [setRawSamples](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#afd13c94e23520dacbc37b4d0fd036a8b) requires the data buffers you pass to be valid during the lifetime of the plot. In your case you pass the local buffers which are invalid as soon as `forwardPlot() ends`

Allocate the buffers in heap instead.

Comment: From the hints above only part 3 (Plotting the title) works... Still do not get what the problem is.

Comment: By "works" do you mean that you can see the title on the plot widget, but not the plot itself? Do you see the axis? Please consider posting a compilable sample which reproduces the problem or upload the project somewhere, as the problem may be somewhere else (like UI file) .

Comment: OK, I will provide an example as soon I have time. What I meant in the comment before, is that I can see the Title. I am can also see the plot area, the axis and I can change the color of the plot axis. But I can not change the scale of both axes (Poit two of your answer). And, most important, the curve is not showing up... Thanks for your comment!

Comment: See the edit above, looks like this is the source of the problem.